# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, tuples

Can anyone help me with this code?

```
Jobs = ()
openFile = open('Jobs.txt')
x = 1
while x != 0:
    Stuff = openFile.readline(x)
    if Stuff != '':
        Jobs.append(Stuff)
    else:
        x = 0
```

This code throws:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I'm using Python 3.6.

Answer (score 9):

In the line:

```
Jobs = ()
```

you create a `tuple`. A `tuple` is immutable and has no methods to add, remove or alter elements. You probably wanted to create a `list` (lists have an [`.append`-method](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)). To create a list use the square brackets instead of round ones:

```
Jobs = []
```

or use the `list`-"constructor":

```
Jobs = list()
```

---

However some suggestions for your code:

`open`ing a file requires that you `close` it again. Otherwise Python will keep the file handle as long as it is running. To make it easier there is a context manager for this:

```
with open('Jobs.txt') as openFile:
    x = 1
    while x != 0:
        Stuff = openFile.readline(x)
        if Stuff != '':
            Jobs.append(Stuff)
        else:
            x = 0
```

As soon as the context manager finishes the file will be closed automatically, even if an exception occurs.

---

It's used very rarely but [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter) accepts two arguments. If you give it two arguments, then it will call the first each iteration and stop as soon as the second argument is encountered. That seems like a perfect fit here:

```
with open('Jobs.txt') as openFile:
    for Stuff in iter(openFile.readline, ''):
        Jobs.append(Stuff)
```

I'm not sure if that's actually working like expected because `openFile.readline` keeps trailing newline characters (`\n`) so if you want to stop at the first empty line you need `for Stuff in iter(openFile.readline, '\n')`. (Could also be a windows thingy on my computer, ignore this if you don't have problems!)

---

This can also be done in two lines, without creating the `Jobs` before you start the loop:

```
with open('Jobs.txt') as openFile:
    # you could also use "tuple" instead of "list" here.
    Jobs = list(iter(openFile.readline, ''))
```

---

Besides [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter) with two arguments you could also use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
import itertools
with open('Jobs.txt') as openFile:
    Jobs = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x != '', openFile))
```

The `lambda` is a bit slow, if you need it faster you could also use `''.__ne__` or `bool` (the latter one works because an empty string is considered `False`):

```
import itertools
with open('Jobs.txt') as openFile:
    Jobs = list(itertools.takewhile(''.__ne__, openFile))
```

Answer (score 0):

The Jobs object you created is a tuple, which is immutable. Therefore, you cannot "append" anything to it.

Try

```
Jobs = []
```

instead, in which you create a list object.

Answer (score 0):

I had also experienced the same problem. But I found the solution. For me this worked.
Problem:

```
w=[]
x=[],
y=[],
z=[]
for i in range(4):
 w.append(i) # doesn't throw error
print(w)
```

This did not give error for `w` because I had initialized `w` to `w = []` without comma(,) and it treated as list but when I applied the same for `x` it gave the error because I have initialized it as `x = [],` with comma here and it treated as tuple.

```
for i in range(4):
 y.append(i) # throws error AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append' 
print(y)
```

This solved for me and I have tried this in python3 in pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

The curved brackets are not the correct bracket for creating lists.
Use the square brackets for lists.